# Pycharm is basically unusable when using a virtualenv interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv using:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

When I use Pycharm configured to the interpreter from that virtualenv, I cannot add variables in run time, I cannot add variables to watches and I can only print the values of some variables, that is to say, the app does not work at all.  This also happens in Pycharm 2017, 2018 and 2019.  The problem further occurs with all modules, even with modules which are basically blank. The exact error message I get is when I try to assign a value to `cc` is:

```
cc=9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kylefoley/codes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3184, in run_ast_nodes
code = compiler(mod, cell_name, "exec")
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

When I run Pycharm using an interpreter which was not created using `virtualenv`, I have no problems.  Now let me demonstrate that I have all of the Pycharm settings done correctly. When I print `sys.version` I get:

```
3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27)
```

Pycharm always prints the interpreter being used on execution and that is:

```
/Users/kylefoley/codes/venv/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE 2.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py"
```

`venv` is directory created by the virtualenv.

[image: configs]

[image: config2]

#

UPDATE

I put all of my site-packages that were in my `venv` folder into the system interpreter and I again encountered the same error.  So it must be a problem with the module that is throwing the error which is

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3184, in run_ast_nodes
```

I don't even know why `IPython` is being used.  This is what the module says where the error is occurring none of which means anything to me:

```
def run_ast_nodes(self, nodelist:ListType[AST], cell_name:str, interactivity='last_expr',
                    compiler=compile, result=None):
    """Run a sequence of AST nodes. The execution mode depends on the
    interactivity parameter.

    Parameters
    ----------
    nodelist : list
      A sequence of AST nodes to run.
    cell_name : str
      Will be passed to the compiler as the filename of the cell. Typically
      the value returned by ip.compile.cache(cell).
    interactivity : str
      'all', 'last', 'last_expr' , 'last_expr_or_assign' or 'none',
      specifying which nodes should be run interactively (displaying output
      from expressions). 'last_expr' will run the last node interactively
      only if it is an expression (i.e. expressions in loops or other blocks
      are not displayed) 'last_expr_or_assign' will run the last expression
      or the last assignment. Other values for this parameter will raise a
      ValueError.

      Experimental value: 'async' Will try to run top level interactive
      async/await code in default runner, this will not respect the
      interactivty setting and will only run the last node if it is an
      expression. 

    compiler : callable
      A function with the same interface as the built-in compile(), to turn
      the AST nodes into code objects. Default is the built-in compile().
    result : ExecutionResult, optional
      An object to store exceptions that occur during execution.

    Returns
    -------
    True if an exception occurred while running code, False if it finished
    running.
    """
    if not nodelist:
        return
    if interactivity == 'last_expr_or_assign':
        if isinstance(nodelist[-1], _assign_nodes):
            asg = nodelist[-1]
            if isinstance(asg, ast.Assign) and len(asg.targets) == 1:
                target = asg.targets[0]
            elif isinstance(asg, _single_targets_nodes):
                target = asg.target
            else:
                target = None
            if isinstance(target, ast.Name):
                nnode = ast.Expr(ast.Name(target.id, ast.Load()))
                ast.fix_missing_locations(nnode)
                nodelist.append(nnode)
        interactivity = 'last_expr'

    _async = False
    if interactivity == 'last_expr':
        if isinstance(nodelist[-1], ast.Expr):
            interactivity = "last"
        else:
            interactivity = "none"

    if interactivity == 'none':
        to_run_exec, to_run_interactive = nodelist, []
    elif interactivity == 'last':
        to_run_exec, to_run_interactive = nodelist[:-1], nodelist[-1:]
    elif interactivity == 'all':
        to_run_exec, to_run_interactive = [], nodelist
    elif interactivity == 'async':
        _async = True
    else:
        raise ValueError("Interactivity was %r" % interactivity)
    try:
        if _async:
            # If interactivity is async the semantics of run_code are
            # completely different Skip usual machinery.
            mod = ast.Module(nodelist)
            async_wrapper_code = compiler(mod, 'cell_name', 'exec')
            exec(async_wrapper_code, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
            async_code = removed_co_newlocals(self.user_ns.pop('async-def-wrapper')).__code__
            if (yield from self.run_code(async_code, result, async_=True)):
                return True
        else:
            for i, node in enumerate(to_run_exec):
                mod = ast.Module([node])
                code = compiler(mod, cell_name, "exec")
                if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
                    return True

            for i, node in enumerate(to_run_interactive):
                mod = ast.Interactive([node])
                code = compiler(mod, cell_name, "single")
                if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
                    return True

        # Flush softspace
        if softspace(sys.stdout, 0):
            print()

    except:
        # It's possible to have exceptions raised here, typically by
        # compilation of odd code (such as a naked 'return' outside a
        # function) that did parse but isn't valid. Typically the exception
        # is a SyntaxError, but it's safest just to catch anything and show
        # the user a traceback.

        # We do only one try/except outside the loop to minimize the impact
        # on runtime, and also because if any node in the node list is
        # broken, we should stop execution completely.
        if result:
            result.error_before_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
        self.showtraceback()
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: You should probably report this bug over at JetBrains' bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: I already did that but if you look at their bug tracker you'll see that requests rarely go answered.

Comment: I always use virtualenv in pycharm, never encountered any of this.

Answer (score 3):

I just decided to write in Terminal

```
pip uninstall iPython
```

That did it.  As far as I know I was not using iPython and have no use for it.

Comment: Most likely installed by anaconda.

Comment: @logic1976 can you mark your question as resolved?